# Interfacing Node-Postgres, Express JS and Node JS

Tags: sql, node.js, database, postgresql, express

## Issue:

So, I'm having a typical issue while trying to store my pagecounter in a database. I'm using Node JS and Node PG through a remote console so I don't know the versions. It's not a connection based problem or anything wrong with my database either as I've tested it using a sample database.

*P.S: I'm new to both javascript and databases(especially) and this might be a silly error so bear with me.*

As you can see from the code, I'm using an old syntax as I'm following an year old video tutorial as part of my course.

I've gone through this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34236867/querying-postgres-db-with-node-postgres) but I don't think that's the issue here.

---

## Observations:

> 1. Everytime, I restart the server, it starts from server.js's counter.
> 2. Henceforth, the counter gets incremented for every alternate manual
>    refresh.
> 3. I've observed that even my Database is getting altered accordingly.

---

## Debug:

> 1. Re-querieng the same <kbd>SELECT</kbd> doesn't work.
> 2. Using a temp variable to hold the count and checking against it has no affect either.
> 3. The request status toggles between `200` and `304` for increment and no change respectively.

---

## Code:

```
var express = require('express');
var morgan = require('morgan');
var path = require('path');
var app = express();
app.use(morgan('combined'));
var crypto = require('crypto');
    var Pool = require('pg').Pool;
    var config = {
        user: 'dragonlordthota717',
        database: 'dragonlordthota717',
        host: 'db.imad.hasura-app.io',
        port: '5432',
        password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD
    };

var pool = new Pool(config);
    var counter = {"pageviews":800};
    var flag = "From server.js";
    app.get('/counter', function (req, res){
      pool.query("SELECT pageviews FROM users WHERE name='Hyperclaw79'",function(err,result){
          if(err){
            res.status(500).send("Flag: "+err.toString());  
          }
          else{
            counter = result.rows[0];
            flag = "From query";
          }
      });
      var cnt = counter.pageviews;
      cnt = parseInt(cnt)+1;
      if(isNaN(cnt)) res.status(500).send(flag+': returned NaN as seen in: '+JSON.stringify(counter));
      else pool.query("UPDATE users SET pageviews = $1 WHERE name = 'Hyperclaw79'",[cnt]);
      return res.send(flag +": " + cnt.toString());
    });
```

I've set my `pageviews` in DB to **850** to get a clarity on what exactly is going on.

However, it has this typical alternating behaviour. Here is the output I've recieved:

```
From server.js: 801
From query: 851
From query: 802
From query: 852
From query: 803
From query: 853
.
.
.
.
.
```

It is clear that, the <kbd>SELECT</kbd> query isn't being sent the first time. Henceforth, all the transactions are being done from the database itself. However, even though the database is supposed to get overwritten by 801 and it should increment accordingly, somehow the old value is returning back alternatively and that too, incremented.

---

It would be really helpful if anyone can find the bug or indicate if I'm mistaken in my logic as I've been at it for a whole day and still am not able to figure this out. Please don't suggest workarounds using external packages like [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg-query) as I do not have admin priveldges over the remote machine.
Well, thanks in advance if you're able to figure this out.

Comment: The line `var counter = {"pageviews":800};` is interfering with you logic for some reason.

Comment: The `pool.query`'s callback gets executed after the line `var cnt = counter.pageviews;`

Comment: You need the whole block starting from `var cnt = counter.pageviews;` inside the else block within `pool.query`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work

```
var express = require('express');
var morgan = require('morgan');
var path = require('path');
var app = express();
app.use(morgan('combined'));
var crypto = require('crypto');
    var Pool = require('pg').Pool;
    var config = {
        user: 'dragonlordthota717',
        database: 'dragonlordthota717',
        host: 'db.imad.hasura-app.io',
        port: '5432',
        password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD
    };

var pool = new Pool(config);
    var counter = {"pageviews":800};
    var flag = "From server.js";
    app.get('/counter', function (req, res){
      pool.query("SELECT pageviews FROM users WHERE name='Hyperclaw79'",function(err,result){
          if(err){
            res.status(500).send("Flag: "+err.toString());  
          }
          else{
            counter = result.rows[0];
            flag = "From query";
            var cnt = counter.pageviews;
            cnt = parseInt(cnt)+1;
            if(isNaN(cnt)) res.status(500).send(flag+': returned NaN as seen in: '+JSON.stringify(counter));
            else pool.query("UPDATE users SET pageviews = $1 WHERE name = 'Hyperclaw79'",[cnt]);
            return res.send(flag +": " + cnt.toString());

          }
      });

    });
```

In the original code, the callback for `pool.query` is called after the counter is read, so the counter is not actually updated when counter is stored in the variable `cnt`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This worked flawlessly. Can you explain why the behaviour was alternating like that though? I assumed that every time the app.get request is made, the query will be executed first and hence counter value would've been overwritten eitherway.

Comment: The first time you read from db, the db has value 850, but after the callback , the value is changed to 800. But your variable `counter` has value '850' , which goes inside db after the next query. This cycle repeats, storing alternate values between the  `800` series and `850` series...

Comment: Oh so that's what was happening I see. Thanks a lot.